# Run background code all the time when Android device is up

Tags: java, android, c++

I want to run some code (mainly record system logs) in the background every certain time. This code runs all time when device is up. I have an app to control the start and stop of this recording code. I have tried putting the recording code in the service, but I found that the service always stops when app exits. This is not what I want. This function needs no notification.

BTW, this function is only for my custom Android system. So I have enough privileges such like system, driver or root. But I still want a way that is "high“ enough and affects the system least. So some normal java code is best, the kernel c/c++ modification to the custom OS is my last choice.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Make a service class and give the permission to the maniefest

Here is the example...

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

and do your stuff in the service, you can set time interval for that.

Comment: I want my code running "all time" when device is up, like a kernel service, no matter whether the app is up. IntentService seems to rely on an app (activity)?

Comment: i thnk it's not possible bcz if user force stop the app then your services will be destroyed...

OR there is another way that u need to take administrator permission for your app. So if once your app got admin permission then no matter what  your app will not gonna be closed ever till u have admin permission

if you wann see sample of that install "App Lock"

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en

Install this app and turn on advance protection and try to force stop that app. Check that. So search for how to get admin permission in android?!!

Comment: Here is the official google Sample how to get admin permission..

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html